# In vsto C#, when copying(no pasting) a range, how to know this range(row/col/rect info)?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, vba

Example in excel 2013,
I select range A1:C3 and ctrl-c or right click copy.
Noticing there will be an animation moving arounding this range, meaning you just copied it.

Now I just want to get this range in my code.

I just hooked the copy invent in windows message. And how can I get this range?
pls help.

Example code:

```
private override onCopy(Excel.Range source){
    //...
    base.onCopy(source);


    //Now I can get the source range when copy happens.
    //But in vsto, there is no such method.
    //Help me to work around
}
```

Comment: It's the `Selection` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835019(v=office.15).aspx) object to get the current selection. But it may return another selection, not just copied.

To get the copied Seletion object you need to set a keyboard hook for intercepting the Ctrl+C keyboard buttons and/or repurspose the ribbon controls.

See [Using shortcut keys to call a function in an Office Add-in](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2010/04/09/using-shortcut-keys-to-call-a-function-in-an-office-add-in.aspx) to get started with Windows Hooks.

Most probably repurposing the ribbon controls will be enough (context menus use the Ribbon UI). See [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.